# Enable Seemless SSO when currently Federated

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Testing out staged roll out of could auth with PSH & SSO

Current setup:
I have a 3rd party Federated domain (Onelogin), Password Hash enabled & SSO disabled

Onelogin is only used as an Identity provider not used for anthing else, woud like to migrate from that to an Azure Password Hash / Passthrough currely weighing up the two: Would like to have MFA, self serving password reset and contional access setup via Azure P1, reading up this might be better with Pass Through, unless i have read wrong?

As part of staged rollout would like to enable Seemliess SSO,
was wondering if I enable Seamless SSO on my domain via powershell ( Enable-AzureADSSOForest -OnPremCredentials $creds) would this cause any disruption / issues with the current federation method?

there is no current SSO with OneLogin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you were in the process of staged rollout. staged rollout doesn't switch domains from federated to managed. You still need to make the final cutover from federated to cloud authentication by using Azure AD Connect or PowerShell.

You can enable seamless SSO and it is triggered only for users who are selected for staged rollout and it won't affect your existing federation setup. Kindly go through the below documents to get a detailed information.

[link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-staged-rollout) and [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-quick-start). If you have any further quires kindly let me know.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you so much!